# Jenkins JIRA trigger multiple projects

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-jira-trigger

Does the project name in Jenkins need to match the project name in JIRA in order for the the Jenkins JIRA Trigger to connect properly? Or is it simply looking for whatever you've set to trigger a build in Jenkins - ie comment, status, transition, etc.

Essentially, how can I best set up the JIRA trigger to separate multiple build projects in Jenkins with multiple projects in JIRA?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have an exact match of a project name in Jenkins indeed. This plugin will only trigger a build when it matches the trigger configuration you have set in the Jenkins job.

Say you want to trigger job **foo** when **bar** project has change in JIRA, you can configure **foo** to have a JQL Filter of `project=bar`. Once this is configured, a Jenkins build will only be triggered when the event sent from JIRA is from project **bar**. Do note that you will need to configure Jenkins to talk to JIRA correctly to make this feature to work in the Global Configuration page (hence becoming bidirectional communication).

Comment: Hi, I filled jql filter with project=TEST, but the jenkins was not triggered.